# Powershell Ping with Conditional Format

Tags: excel, powershell

[image: Code Error]Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to make my ping script ping a list of hostnames in a txt output dead or alive. Then do conditional formatting in excel so output the CSV. Want to make it easier on the eyes so Red in dead and Green is alive. If I don't have to output to excel and can have the conditional format work in the CSV then I'm ok with that. I have attached a Picture of the codes that are being thrown.

```
# Set up file paths
$hostList = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\hnames.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\output.csv"

# Read list of host names from text file
$hosts = Get-Content $hostList

# Initialize output array
$output = @()

# Loop through host names and ping each one
foreach ($host in $hosts) {
    $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $host -Count 1 -Quiet
    
    # Add host and status to output array
    $status = if ($pingResult) {"Alive"} else {"Dead"}
    $output += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Hostname = $host
        Status = $status
    }
}

# Export output array to CSV file
$output | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation

# Set up Excel application
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($outputFile)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Set up range of cells to highlight
$range = $worksheet.Range("B2:B$($hosts.Count+1)")

# Set up conditional formatting
$colorRed = 255
$colorGreen = 50
$conditionalFormat = $range.FormatConditions.Add(3,0,$status)
$conditionalFormat.Interior.Color = $colorRed*256*256 + $colorGreen*256
$conditionalFormat.Font.Color = -4142

# Save and close Excel file
$workbook.Save()
$workbook.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices]
```

Comment: CSV files do not store formatting, so you're stuck with Excel.

Comment: `$host` is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#host). You cannot use that name as self-defined variable.

Comment: And as for the `[System.Runtime.Interopservices]` error, did you mean `$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)` ?

Comment: so anything with Host i would have to change that variables. I built the code google and searching Stack. I am still a beginner in Shell.